# I don't seem to be able to save Layer Styles in QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have created and saved layer styles, not recently I admit but have done in the past. For some reason or other I just don't seem to be able to save any new ones in QGIS. No file is created. It does not even save changes to existing ones, even though it says I am replacing it. I surely must be doing something wrong, but don't know what. I can make the changes in the style and that's fine, it just won't save.

I'm running on MS Vista.

Comment: What version of QGIS are you using? Have you changed versions since it last worked?

Comment: I'm using 1.8 and it is the same version I used initially. I've searched for others with the same issue but found nothing. I've tried new projects, completely new styles.

Comment: Do you have write access to the drive/folder you are trying to save the styles to?

Comment: Yes, I have access and tried other directories to save as well, but always the same problem.

Comment: I just tried here as both .sld and .qml and it worked fine. Can you try in 1.9 and/or an older version? Does it work on another computer?

Comment: I tried to save as SLD and I get a message
_ERROR: Failed to created SLD style file as . Check file permissions and retry._
I tried in various locations and I still get the same error. Is it possible a Windows Update has added something in the security? Do I need to set special permissions in a directory?

Apart from that, I don't have another machine to try out an other versions yet and I'm reluctant to mess with my current system. I can live with this for now as it's not something I need to do very often, but it is a nuisance. I will have a Windows 8 box in a about a week, so could try then.

Comment: It is clearly a permissions problem then. Not sure what else to say if you have confirmed permissions. Can you try to run QGIS as an administrator and see if that works?

Comment: I have admin permissions anyway, so there is nothing more I can do. Does anyone know if there are permissions set by QGIS when it is installed? I can only think something else has changed them as I certainly have not. The defaults directory is under my login too.

Comment: I have just checked, and according to the properties I have full control over the directory. I'll have to wait until I get my new PC very soon, than I'll install it there.

Where do I get version 1.9? I can't seem to find a genuine install for it.

Comment: The easiest way to get 1.9 is via the OSGEO4W installer.

Comment: Thanks @darrencope. I installed 1.8 on an old laptop. I then shared the style directory on my pc over my home network. Working on the laptop I can save styles in this shared directory, so it is something weird going on. Not a QGIS issue.

Comment: Hopefully this adds rather than subverts the conversation: I've had this problem before a while back. Recently upgraded to 2.2 & 2.3 on windows7. Same problem with both 2.2 & 2.3 whether run as user or admin (on single user machine), saving in normal documents folder where QGis outputs everything else.

Comment: Related: this was a logged bug that may not have been fixed: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8285

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there is a problem with the settings on the PC, probably due to some windows update. I now have a new one and will install on there. It would have been good to know exactly what caused the problem in the first place though!!!